# SPARQL query to print individuals based on dataproperty values

Tags: ontology

I would like to query individuals of an ontology(owl file) based on the data property value. how to write sparql query.[ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPYPf.png)

Here i need to find all the individuals with hasAcidity > 5. please help to write SPARQL query. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show what query you have constructed so far (plus what is wrong with the results of that query). If you ask a concrete question then people might be able to help.

Comment: the ontology i am working on contains some individuals on which different users have different preference level.I would like to retreive all individuals whose user1_preference is greater than 0.8.Associated with individuals i have an data property hasUser1_preference with some values.hasUser1_preference is a subproperty of hasUserpreference. while i am running query i get all the individuals corresponding to all hasUserPreference(including User2_preference, User3_preference etc...)not just User1_preference.    Query :    select ?s where{?s ?hasUser1_preference '0.9'};